# Xcode 11 b5: First start error message - should I worry?

Tags: xcode

After installing Xcode 11 Beta 5, installing the tools, and starting it for the first time, I get this error:

```
Loading a plug-in failed.
Domain: DVTPlugInErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: The plug-in “com.apple.dt.UVKit” at path “/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged.
Recovery Suggestion: The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.
User Info: {
    DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey = "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit, 0): Symbol not found: _$s2IDs12IdentifiablePTl\n  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib\n in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit";
    DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey = "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit";
    DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey = "com.apple.dt.UVKit";
    NSFilePath = "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework";
}
--
The bundle “UVKit” couldn’t be loaded.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 3588
Failure Reason: The bundle couldn’t be loaded.
Recovery Suggestion: Try reinstalling the bundle.
User Info: {
    NSBundlePath = "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework";
    NSDebugDescription = "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit, 265): Symbol not found: _$s2IDs12IdentifiablePTl\n  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib\n in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit";
    NSFilePath = "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit";
}
--
```

The reinstallation of Xcode b5 did not change the situation. How can I fix this problem, if at all?

Answer (score 1):

> There are known incompatibilities when using SwiftUI in Xcode 11 beta 5 on macOS Catalina beta 4. Update to macOS Catalina beta 5 when it becomes available.

– 10.15 beta 4 release notes.

I was having the same problem, just updated to 10.15 beta 5 and I am able to access the live preview again. I'm using:

- macOS 10.15 **beta 5**
- Xcode 11 **beta 5**

Answer (score 0):

well, the error occurred *after* upgrading and installing on macOS 10.15b5. Funny enough: everything seems to work fine, at least I did encounter no problems up to now.